# Handling large integers in c++

Tags: c++

How can i handle very large integers like 2^100000000 in c++?

I found no solution for this on internet that gives an exact answer.

Is there any mechanism that gives correct value in c++ for such large integers?

Comment: Have you searched on stackoverflow? There must be at least one answer suggesting e.g. gmp. There's no _standard_ way (yet), but there are a ton of ways. Look closer.

Comment: Try searching for [BigNum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic).

Comment: It's a bit out of the standard range to call it "integer" -- your number has 3 *million* digits. Maybe that's why your search turned up nothing.

Comment: i searched on stackoverflow and about bignum ... but very long process than my program :(

Comment: What do you mean by 'handle'? Do you just want to get the decimal representation of such a number or do you want to do calculations with it?

Answer (score 4):

What you are looking for is called *arbitrary precision arithmetic*, you will find numerous libraries and educational resources with some googling.

Answer (score 0):

You can represent given number as a string and convert it to array with integer digits. But the simplest way to google by keywords "long arithmetic c++ library" or something.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to use a Computer Algebra System (CAS), which would represent your expression like this:

```
class Pow : public Expr {
  Number base;
  Number exp;
};

Pow expr = new Pow(2, 100*1000*1000);
```

A CAS then allows you to manipulate these expressions structurally instead of the concrete values.